# I have my desired pixels, how can I crop the image between them?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove the white space around my images. I clustered my images into 2 clusters => the white background and the item.
I have also found where is the first and last pixel of the image, and I want to crop between them but I don't know how. Can you guys help me?

These are 2 sample images. I want to remove the white background as much as possible.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ7wK.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16fle.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# reshape the image to a 2D array of pixels and 3 color values (RGB)
pixel_values = image.reshape((-1, 3))
# convert to float
pixel_values = np.float32(pixel_values)
print(pixel_values.shape)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.2)
k = 2
_, labels, (centers) = cv2.kmeans(pixel_values, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# convert back to 8 bit values
centers = np.uint8(centers)

# flatten the labels array
labels = labels.flatten()

# convert all pixels to the color of the centroids
segmented_image = centers[labels.flatten()]

# reshape back to the original image dimension
segmented_image = segmented_image.reshape(image.shape)

# mask boundries
non_white_pixels = np.array(np.where(segmented_image != 255))
first_none_white_pixel = non_white_pixels[:,0]
last_none_white_pixel = non_white_pixels[:,-1]
print(f'first white pixel: {first_none_white_pixel}')
print(f'last white pixel: {last_none_white_pixel}')

# start and end of the image border
white_pixels = np.array(np.where(segmented_image == 255))
first_white_pixel = white_pixels[:,0]
last_white_pixel = white_pixels[:,-1]
print(f'first white pixel: {first_white_pixel}')
print(f'last white pixel: {last_white_pixel}')

# show the image
plt.imshow(segmented_image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should the crop result in a square image or are you expecting a transparent background like in a svg format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the findContours method of OpenCV.
The way I see it:

1. Convert your image to gray
2. Apply a bitwise_not operation on your image.
3. Apply a threshold so that the gray color in your first image is set correctly for further processing.
4. Apply findContours.
5. Get the minimum/maximum x and y values from the contour result.
6. Use the python slicing method to retrieve the interesting part of your image.
7. Save your image or display it.

In python, this means:

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread("1.png")
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
height, width = image.shape
image = cv.bitwise_not(image)
_, image = cv.threshold(image, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
image = cv.bitwise_not(image)
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv.imwrite("2.png", image)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but What if I want to apply this on an RGB color?